# Finding the zero divisiors of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In doing a homework question to find the zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, I have a theory that, in general, $\mathbb{Z}_{n}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$ (or equivalently, $\{[m]\in\mathbb{Z}_{n}\mid \gcd(m,n)>1\}$) is exactly the set of zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. Is this true? How might I prove it?

Comment: While correct don't bastardize the word "theory" more than it already has by saying such :) You had an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

Note that the $gcd(m,n)$ can be written as an integer linear combination of $m,n$.

Let $m$ be relatively prime to $n$. (i.e $gcd(m,n)=1$). Then there are $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that: $xm+yn=1 \Rightarrow xm = 1 \text{mod} \, n$

So $x\, \text{mod} \, n$  is the inverse of $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. In particular $m$ is invertible, hence cannot be a zero-divisor.

On the other hand, if $1<d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d|m,d|n$ then

$$m \cdot \frac{n}{d} =\frac{m}{d} \cdot n = 0 \, \text{mod} n$$ so $m$ is a zero divisor, as required.

(note that $\frac{n}{d} \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$).